# Volley : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-volley

i want to collect information from server using volley then display in the listview.before this diplay information on the listview,want to add first in arraylist.But the problem,i receive this error below.Hope you guys can help me solve this problem.

**ERROR**

```
I/art: Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 52(1664B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 176MB/177MB, paused 99.553ms total 643.892ms
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 323.775ms for cause HeapTrim
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 1.769s
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 98.745ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.468ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 192MB to 192MB
I/art: Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(576B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 176MB/192MB, paused 101.770ms total 2.222s
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 2.108s
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 98.256ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.957ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 192MB to 192MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 18(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 176MB/192MB, paused 100.852ms total 2.235s
I/art: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 29MB allocation
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 2.106s
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 98.003ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.912ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 192MB to 192MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 36(1216B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 7% free, 176MB/192MB, paused 100.742ms total 2.231s
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 100.382ms
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 192MB to 192MB
E/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 30536292 byte allocation with 15988544 free bytes and 15MB until OOM"
I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 1.703s for cause HeapTrim
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.631ms
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.846ms
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout, PID: 12350
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 30536292 byte allocation with 15988544 free bytes and 15MB until OOM
                      at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:118)
                      at net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.volley.NotisBackgroundTask$1.onResponse(NotisBackgroundTask.java:50)
                      at net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.volley.NotisBackgroundTask$1.onResponse(NotisBackgroundTask.java:39)
                      at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:72)
                      at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //initialize toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        //initialize tablayout
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        //create create two tab and add those tab inside tablayout object (content not included,just tab)
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Aduan"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Semakan"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Notis"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        //initialize viewpager
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        //initialize fragment pager adapter
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount(),MainActivity.this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
}
```

**Pager.java**

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.volley.NotisBackgroundTask;

public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    int tabCount;


    public Pager(FragmentManager fm, int tabCount,Context context) {
        super(fm);
        //set context
        this.context = context;
        //get count of the tab layout
        this.tabCount= tabCount;
    }

    //if user either tab,the tab position will send to this method and open new tab content inside fragment.
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();

                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                NotisBackgroundTask notisBackgroundTask = new NotisBackgroundTask(context);
                Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
    //get total number of tab
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return tabCount;
    }
}
```

**NotisBackgroundTask.java**

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.volley;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;

import net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.MainActivity;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by User on 1/24/2017.
 */

public class NotisBackgroundTask {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Notis> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    public NotisBackgroundTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        callNotisFromServer();

    }

    public void callNotisFromServer(){

        // make json request (volley)

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.1.106/android/notis_android.php", (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                //get all information from json
                int count = 0;
                while(count <response.length()){
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                        Notis notis = new Notis(jsonObject.getString("time_mula"),
                                jsonObject.getString("time_tamat"),jsonObject.getString("dt_mula"),jsonObject.getString("dt_tamat"),
                                jsonObject.getString("notis_sebab"),jsonObject.getString("notis_lokasi"));
                        arrayList.add(notis);
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        Log.d("message:",e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("Volley ERROR:",error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        MySingleton.getmInstances(context).addRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);


    }

}
```

**Tab3.java**

```
package net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.volley.Notis;
import net.simplifiedcoding.androidtablayout.volley.NotisBackgroundTask;

/**
 * Created by User on 1/24/2017.
 */

public class Tab3 extends Fragment{


    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab3,null);



        return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an infinite loop, you never increment count in the below block:

```
int count = 0;
while(count <response.length()){
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
        Notis notis = new Notis(jsonObject.getString("time_mula"),
                jsonObject.getString("time_tamat"),jsonObject.getString("dt_mula"),jsonObject.getString("dt_tamat"),
                jsonObject.getString("notis_sebab"),jsonObject.getString("notis_lokasi"));
        arrayList.add(notis);
    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.d("message:",e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

To fix this try adding a `count++;` after you add the item

Comment: how can i forget add those,Thanks you sir.